# jProfiler GUI not showing properly on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java-7, ubuntu-14.04, jprofiler

I'm not sure if this is a java problem or is related to ubuntu. I'm on an ubuntu 14.04 machine and I have both Java 6 (jdk_1.6.0_43) and Java 7(jdk_1.7.0_51). JAVA_HOME is set to java 7 and that is what my PATH env var is referring to. So Java -version would give me the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Now I installed jprofiler (v 8.0.7) for linux by downloading the setup script and running it (https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files). But when I run jprofiler from command line, I get a non workable gui showing up with all window sizes messed up. I cannot resize the windows so I have no access to the functionality. The quickstart window shows up but clicking anywhere on that window makes the whole window disappear.

[image: See the image]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Please try to edit $HOME/.jprofiler8/config.xml and replace `rememberWindowSizes="true"` with `rememberWindowSizes="false"`. Does that make any difference? Do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: The above did not help. Actually it's important in this case to keep the rememberWindowSize="true". It seems like an ubuntu display issue (I have 2 monitors). but using the alt+F7 shortcut I could get hold of the jprofiler windows and move or resize them. Then these sizes would be remembered the next time the gui is shown. This is a workaround and does not resolve the issue.

Comment: mkhezr's solution worked. Press alt+F7, it will grab the screen to the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the GraphicsConfiguration returned the wrong screen bounds. JProfiler 8.1 will add a safeguard against that case.

---

**Update 2015-05-11**

The problem was not fixed in all cases in 8.1, a more comprehensive fix will be available in JProfiler 9

Comment: I still have the same problem with JProfiler 8.1.4 under Ubuntu 12.04 with both Java 7 and 8.

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com, we would need your help in resolving this problem by trying a special build